# Creating a blog hurts my product page?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

So I created a blog at the end of March 2021 and started posting 2 to 3 posts per month.
In August 2021, I started posting more often.

My whole goal with the blog is to bring new potential customers to my main product and therefore to the main product page too.
However, this is how my Google Search Console number of views look for my product page.

Looks like there's a trend going down:

[image]

Despite having my blog views going up:

[image]

I'm just wondering, can perhaps the blog posts have any influence on this trend going down for my main website?

I'm aware of keyword cannibalization and I try not to compete with myself on my own blog posts, but can there be any other side effects?

My page structure is the following:

```sh
example.com/product/
example.com/blog/
```

Comment: How do you link your pages?  Do your product pages link to your blog?  Do product pages deep link to various individual blog posts?   Same questions other way around:  Do your blog posts link to your product pages, including deep links to specific relevant products?

Comment: If the goal is to bring people to the product, why not measure their whole journey using something like Google Analytics? The Search Console data can only show entry points from Google, not where users click to while they visit.

Comment: http://www.visualsitemapper.com

Comment: The blog posts link to the product page. The product page has a single link to the blog index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What You're Seeing in Search Console Looks Great

Your blog content is *working*! I'll explain why in a second, but this is the sort of ramp we want to see early on!

[image: performance graph in Google Search Console showing an increase in impressions that highlights the increase over a two month period]

Your goal to bring new potential customers to your main product page(s) from your blog posts is spot on for an organic content strategy.

The *minor* drop in impressions (the amount of times your pages was shown in the results for a query) that you're seeing with your product pages looks totally natural to me.

Demand/Search Volume fluctuate a lot - it's likely that just less people were searching for the types of products that you offer.

I would not expect your blog content to cannibalize your product pages - topically, I'd expect those to be pretty distinct. For example, your blog page *about* a product isn't going to have a checkout button or product description, etc.

You'd rank your product pages for keywords like "Buy Example Products Online", or "Purchase Example Products". Possible blog content might be something like "How to choose an example product", or "The Best Example Products to Buy 2021 Complete Guide".

No cannibalization there.

---

### For sites that sell or market *anything*, generally speaking, we have 3 types of users:

1. Top-of-funnel
2. Middle-funnel
3. Bottom-of-funnel

[image]

### Top of Funnel

When I'm implementing a content strategy (like you are) I typically like to see ~70% of traffic to be Top-of-funnel.

The goal is to increase our traffic by ranking blog content, articles, guides, etc for medium to high volume informational searches.

In essence, for the user, this satisfies the question **"What do I need?"**. I would *want* your blog content to out rank your product pages for this type of traffic.

This content is also how you're going to earn the most links (which you'll need for your product pages)

### Middle Funnel

~20% of traffic is healthy for middle funnel content. These are your case studies, white papers, product comparisons, webinars, newsletters, and etc.

This satisfies the question **"Why should I buy it from you?"**.

### Bottom Funnel

The remaining ~10% of traffic is where your product pages shine. The traffic you want coming to these pages is users that are already decided. They know what they want.

You answer the question **"Why should I buy now?"**.

Product SERPs are highly competitive tho, which means to really get those pages ranking you need a lot of links and authority. Hence, our top-of-funnel content strategy.

---

Keep going with the blog content and it will pay off, but know that only a small percentage of users will *actually* convert after engaging with it. If your content is great, those who don't will remember you in the future.

But the overall point I'm getting at is that your different types of content should be ranking for different types of searches/intent based on where they're at in your buyers funnel.

Perhaps start a newsletter and add a form to your blog with a call to action for readers to subscribe for more. **Keep the users in your funnel!** Those that do subscribe, now go into your middle funnel.

Supplement this with other marketing/advertising as well. I'd absolutely be running some PPC on top of my organic if I sold products. That is the best way to capture bottom-funnel traffic - you'd want to drive it to a product landing page where the users can buy now.

**Additional tips**

- Review your query report in the performance tab in Search Console to get ideas for content. What queries are you not covering?
- I'd recommend using a free SEO tool like [Ubersuggest](https://neilpatel.com/ubersuggest/) to help inform your content strategy. Perhaps invest in something a bit more robust if you keep going.
- Brush up on search intent. Here's a good article https://ahrefs.com/blog/search-intent/
- If you're not using Google Analytics, definitely start.

Comment: Mike, that's a great example of how a marketing funnel is supposed to work and how it correlates to a blog!

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated reply! It helped a lot!

Comment: @Steve I'm glad to hear that you found this answer useful.

Answer (score 3):

There are really only two mechanisms that could cause your main site to lose search impressions when you blog more:

- Keyword cannibalization
- The blog is low quality and is hurting your site overall

You say you are aware of keyword cannibalization because you try not to compete with yourself.   However, the majority of your search queries are "long tail."  It is very difficult to post more in the same subject area without changing the most relevant page on your site for at least some long-tail queries. I'd spot check some long-tail keywords that used to go to your product pages and see if your blog is ranking for them now.

Because your blog is growing in traffic, I don't think it is likely to be low quality.

When you create a blog, it is unlikely to bring new visitors into your product pages directly from search in the short term.   Initially the blog itself will rank and users will come in from search to pages on the blog.   Eventually if people link to the blog, those links could help boost rankings for your entire site.   However it could take years for your blog to accumulate enough links to have a ranking effect on the rest of your site.

You can do two things to make your blog more valuable in terms of product sales:

- Run "house ads" in your blog to sell your own products to readers.  That can turn some of that blog traffic into paying customers.
- Create additional links from blog posts to relevant product pages.  More links, especially deep links, to your product pages are a signal to search engines that those pages are important.  It will eventually help them rank better (and faster.)