# What motivates users to click on "About Us" versus "Home" after landing on a blog page

Tags: seo, goal-tracking, conversions

My site is a small niche site, primarily using informative blogs to attract readers.

Some users click on "Contact Us" from the footer.  Others click on "About us" or "Home" in the menu bar.

I'm trying to better implement [conversion funnels](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137104/creating-a-blog-hurts-my-product-page/137117#137117) - and understand where users who are more motivated will click next after reading a blog post.

Are there any studies that indicate what motivates users to click on one of the mentioned links versus the other two?  Is one of these pages more conducive to a conversion funnel than the other two?

Comment: My guess is that they're more likely to click on "Home" to get an overall impression of the site after reading a blog post, but hopefully other users like @MikeCiffone will be able to say more definitively.

Comment: I would just like to point out that some users wanting to estimate the credibility of a website by checking its about-section before they expose themselves to more of its content on the homepage gives me hope for humanity.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, there cannot be a definitively right or wrong answer to this question due to its subjective nature. However, based on my past SEO experience and some freshly completed research inspired by your query, I offer this opinionated answer atop a foundation of facts.

Neither the home page, nor the contact page, nor the about page, can be pitted against the other in a weighted comparison and proven to be more valuable than another, or even more likely to drive conversion, for that matter. And here is why.

## Home Page

The home page is essentially a broad version of a landing page. It is the digital front door of the company or individual it represents and is responsible for most of the crucial first impressions your site will make on a potential customer or subscriber.

So naturally, after navigating to your site via a landing page or blog post, a certain percentage of your visitors will wish to refocus and get an overall picture of your company by "backing out" to view the home page. This group of users is in **a fickle frame of mind** because their loyalty is still extremely shallow or perhaps even nonexistent. Your homepage needs to be **well designed, unique, and load quickly** to **establish and retain their interest**.

## About Us

For other users who may already know a little bit about you or your brand name and be inspired (hopefully) by the content from the blog post, the About Us page is a more likely destination. This group of individuals wants to know what you are all about and **see if your motto, vibe, mantra, or mission statement clicks with them**.

People shop online much in the same way they date online and donate money online. They are selective. Something about **your business's persona needs to resonate with them**, even if only subconsciously, to pick you over the next candidate. This group of users has expressed additional interest in what you bring to the table, and they are estimated to be **40-50% committed** to the sale.

If your site sports **a well-designed and engaging *About Us* page**, you are well-positioned to **reinforce the level of trust and familiarity** your potential customers have with your brand and/or company.

## Contact Us

Once a user navigates to the Contact Us page, it can usually be assumed that they are nearing the last part of the funnel. Studies have shown that **they are about 70% committed to the sale**. However, if their attempt to reach out becomes difficult or confusing, most potential buyers will quickly bail out with a sour taste in their mouth and likely never take **that crucial final step into the checkout process**.

The contact page should be **easy to locate and navigate**, the primary contact details should easily stand out, and **most of all, it should feel welcoming** to the visitor. They should get the sense that you are also invested in closing the deal. At this stage of the game, if there are any lingering doubts in their mind, **it is crucial for them to feel comfortable and safe** when reaching out to talk to a real person.

References:

- [*The Must-Haves On Your Company's Contact Us Page (With Examples)*](https://blog.thomasnet.com/the-must-haves-on-your-companys-contact-us-page)
- [*About Us Page SEO: How Do You Write A Perfect “About Us” Page?*](https://morningscore.io/about-us-page-seo/)

Comment: In the UK (based on EU online selling regulations) it's obligatory to have the registered business address on the website. If it's not in your footer I'll go searching for it. People might be checking for a phone number before purchase; using email when a company doesn't want to bother responding is awful. A phone number is an indicator of ability to get customer service (not foolproof by any means).